# convexity of infimum over 1 variable, constraint

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm having a hard time proving to myself that the following function is convex:
$$f'(x')= \inf_{Ax = x'} f(x)$$

where $f(x)$ is convex.

i.e., I'm trying to show

$$f'(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \le tf'(x_1)+(1-t)f'(x_2)\tag{1}$$

where $t\in[0,1]$
By definition,

$$f'(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \le f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \le tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$$

But how does this relate this to $(1)$?

Comment: Your "by definition" inequality is inaccurate, in that you didn't account for the action of $A$ in your definition of $f'$. You could have written it correctly as $$f'(tAx_1 + (1-t)Ax_2) \le f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) ...$$ I presume $x \in \Bbb R^n, x' \in \Bbb R^m$ and $A : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is a surjective linear map?

Comment: any info given on $A$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem: Suppose $f(x)$ is convex. Prove that $g(y) = \inf\limits_{Ax = y} f(x)$ is convex.

*Proof*: Let $t\in [0, 1]$. We need to prove that
$$g(t y_1 + (1-t)y_2) \le t g(y_1) + (1-t)g(y_2).\tag{1}$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. From the definition of infimum, there exists $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that
$Ax_1=y_1$, $Ax_2 = y_2$, $f(x_1) \le g(y_1) + \epsilon$ and $f(x_2) \le g(y_2) + \epsilon$.
Thus, we have
\begin{align}
g(ty_1 + (1-t)y_2) &\le f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)\\
& \le tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2) \\
&\le t (g(y_1) + \epsilon) + (1-t)(g(y_2) + \epsilon)\\
& = tg(y_1) + (1-t)g(y_2) + \epsilon.
\end{align}
Since this holds for any $\epsilon > 0$, (1) holds. We are done.

Reference: Boyd and Vandenberghe, "Convex Optimization".